# CommandBar Behavior When Keyboard Is Show

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, win-universal-app

I have `CommandBar` in my **UWP** App :

```
<Page.BottomAppBar>
    <CommandBar x:Name="BottomBar">
        <AppBarButton Icon="Save" Label="Save" Click="OnSave"/>
        <AppBarButton Icon="Clear" Label="Reset"/>
    </CommandBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>
```

[image: UWP CommandBar]

In `Windows Phone 8.1`, when `Keyboard` is show, if when I press `Save` it will execute `OnSave` method.
But in **UWP**, pressing Save will hide `Keyboard` not executing `Click` event.

I want this `CommandBar` behave like `Windows Phone 8.1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not test it, but you can try **IsTabStop="False"**:

```
<AppBarButton Icon="Save" Label="Save" Click="OnSave" IsTabStop="False"/>
```